# Not sure what my issue is with reading in a text file

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to read in a text file containing a monopoly board from a text file and for some reason, I cannot do it via the way I normally do, can anyone see anything here that I'm missing?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class properties
{
private:
    ifstream infile("Monopoly.txt");
    string line;
    while (getline(infile, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        int i, j;
        if (!(iss >> i >> j)) 
        { 
            break;
        }                                        
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the **symptom**?  "Not Working" is not really a problem we can diagnose.  Does the code compile? run? seg-fault? any errors? incorrect output?

Comment: I don't even see a method in here!   I see a class, with some code outside any method body.  I'm guessing this does not even compile?

Comment: @abelenky is correct. The problem isn't the file. It is that you wrote nonsense. You need a function. You just can't put code inside a class declaration. You should have had errors for this.

Comment: "_I cannot do it via the way I normally do, can anyone see anything here that I'm missing?_" anything seem unusual in general with your code? Because if you have done this before, like you said, then this should be a simple error on your part.

Comment: Ok, in main, all I have is a welcome message, it's not compiling and giving me the following errors



"expected a type specifier" - that's on the ifstream infile; line


"expected a declaration" - on the while statement



Now, the reason I cannot see an issue is I have had this code before that did compile and run just fine, hell all I've done is copy and paste it from that project and changed the text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot do it via the way I normally do, can anyone see anything here that I'm missing?

The *mistake* you have made in your code is that you have class with code in it that is not a part of any defined method. A class it can have fields that are variables and/or functions, but it cannot have code directly in it, which you have done.

You need to take the code from your class and put it inside a **public** function declared inside the class. Then in your `main()` function, create an object of that class and call that function as a field of that object in `main()`. That should sort the problem.

EDIT: By the way, unless you are storing your file in the default location where all files are stored by the compiler, you should specify the directory in which the file is located. Something like this:

```
 ifstream infile("C:\\...\\Monopoly.txt"); add the directory just in front of the file name
```

Would allow you to use the directory of your choice rather than depending on the default one set by the compiler.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain where I went wrong? So that I can fix my answer?

Comment: I recently had someone downvote me for answering a question that they thought shouldn't be answered.  There are all sorts of attitudes on this site.  I upvoted you.

Comment: @stark Thanks for the reply, I was wondering whether something was incorrect with my answer. The downvoter did not _even_ give a reason for downvoting the answer.

Comment: Thanks, yea, I didn't just paste the whole code, just the class I was having issues with and includes I had, in case I missed one I needed.

And you're completely right about some of the attitudes on here, I'm only looking for some guidance, I'm no expert and how else would I become one in time without some help?

Comment: True, @SCBGamingPresents. Good to know that my answer came useful. Can you select the checkmark next to my answer? It should turn green when you do so. Thanks!